# Нет адреса отправителя

Tags: сервер, debian, email, postfix, telnet

Имеем такую картину: Если мы подключаемся по telnet 127.0.0.1 25 или 192.168.0.107, и пытаемся отправить письмо - всё нормально

```
Return-Path: <kk@dsds.ru>
X-Original-To: root@volmed.org.ru
delivered-To: root@volmed.org.ru
Received: from dsds.ru (unknown [192.168.1.105])
    by Debian-Server (Postfix) with SMTP id 35460421D42
    for <root@volmed.org.ru>; Thu, 16 Apr 2020 10:54:16 +0700 (+07)
Message-Id: <20200416035421.35460421D42@Debian-Server>
Date: Thu, 16 Apr 2020 10:54:16 +0700 (+07)
From: kk@dsds.ru`
```

Но, если мы отправим письмо на внешний ip адрес. (67.158.***.***)

```
Return-Path: <loi@ash.ru>
X-Original-To: root@volmed.org.ru
Delivered-To: root@volmed.org.ru
Received: from ash.ru (67-***.****.****.rostelecom.ru [67.***.****.****])
    by Debian-Server (Postfix) with SMTP id 93664421D42
    for <root@volmed.org.ru>; Thu, 16 Apr 2020 10:52:40 +0700 (+07)
```

Comment: `Sender address rejected: Domain not found; from=<loi@ah.ru>`

Comment: вроде бы тут был комментарий с вопросом мне «как это отключить». «отключать это» не стоит. вы же вряд ли хотите значительно увеличить количество спама, которое будет пропускать (вместо удаления) ваш почтовый сервер. правильнее будет ставить обратный адрес с доменной частью существующего домена. если всё-таки надо пропускать какие-то локальные домены, то объявите их в конфигурации как локальные. не помню, как в postfix это называется. что-то вроде localdomains.

Comment: Спасибо, уже исправил. Да, действительно. Сервер не мог это подставить `Return-Path: <loi@ash.ru>
X-Original-To: root@volmed.org.ru
Delivered-To: root@volmed.org.ru
Received: from ash.ru (67-56.457.235.rostelecom.ru [67.56.457.235])
    by Debian-Server (Postfix) with SMTP id 93664421D42
    for <root@volmed.org.ru>; Thu, 16 Apr 2020 10:52:40 +0700 (+07)`